# Uploading multiple files asp.net mvc4 in a single form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to upload multiple files in one form and I have tried different ways.

This is my model

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MovieMetadata))]
public partial class Movie
{

}

class MovieMetadata
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime releaseDate { get; set; }

    public string storyline { get; set; }

    public Binary poster { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime? duration { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Binary trailer { get; set; }
}
```

One of the files that I want to upload is a video, so I put this tag in my Web.config to upload a file less than 1 GB, I put a big number because I will not know the size of the video

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="102400"/>
```

My Controller is the following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //saving the movie
            OperationStatus opStatus = Repository.Save(movie);

            if (!opStatus.Status)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }

        return View(movie);
    }
```

Here is my View:

```
@model MoviesModel.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MoviesLayout.cshtml";
}

    @section createMovie{
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="gallMemberBox">

            <div class="leftFormContent">
                <a href="#">Movie Name</a>

                <div class="imgTmpl">
                    <!--solo hay que especificar el src de la imagen-->
                    <img src="../../Content/img/imgTest.jpg" alt="" />  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rightFormContent">

                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title)

                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)
                </div>

                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.releaseDate)

                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.releaseDate)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.releaseDate)
                </div>

                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.duration)

                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="time1" size="10" />
                    </div>
                    <pre><code></code></pre>
                </div>

                <div>
                    @Html.Label("Poster")

                    <input name="poster" value="C:" id="poster" type="file" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    @Html.Label("Trailer")

                    <input name="trailer" value="" id="trailer" type="file" />
                </div>

                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.storyline)

                    <textarea id="storyline"></textarea>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Create" />

            </div>

            <div class="clearBoth"></div>
        </div> 
    }
}

@section scripts{       
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.timePicker.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ()
        {
            // Default.
            $("#time1").timePicker(
                {
                    startTime: "00.00",
                    endTime: new Date(0, 0, 0, 6, 30, 0),
                    show24Hours: true,
                    separator: ':',
                    step: 3
                }
            );
        })
    </script>
}

@section styles{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/timePicker.css")
}
```

This includes the timepicker.js and css(inside the section style). Start time is to display the first option of time to select, the hour 00:00 and end time was 06:30, show24hours option hides from the control am and pm format, step: 3 means that the control will have all the hours in with the previous format with .3 minutes of difference. The sequence is like this: 00:00 00:03 00:06.... 06:27 06:30. I took it from this site https://github.com/perifer/timePicker/blob/master/index.htm

The problem is the following, when I tried to submit my form with all data(including the fields that are not required, first I got this message:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64
>   character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character
>   among the padding characters.

I resolved it with this code:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "poster, trailer")]Movie movie, HttpPostedFileBase poster, HttpPostedFileBase trailer)
```

So I excluded poster and trailer field and I passed them to the controller like HttpPostedFileBase, thats work but my ModelState.IsValid is false. I thought that it could be a problem of my timepicker, so I excluded the duration field from the View and I tried again, and again I got false. I tried to put use this:

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formCollection)
```

and with the post just came two keys, title and releaseDate. What about the others? What about ModelState.IsValid with the false value? Can I resolve my problem with a strong type and without the HttpPostedFileBase extra parameters that I put in the Create method of the controller?(Something like this: )

```
public ActionResult Create(Movie movie)
```

with the posted files included inside of it?

Comment: @Mortalus  please some help.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov please some help

Comment: @PaulCalcraft please some help

Comment: @smokestudley please some help

Comment: @RajKaimal please some help

Comment: The ModelState.IsValid = false becomes with one error in releaseDate, I'm using DatePicker of jquery, so I put the other fields empty and just filled the required fields(title, and releaseDate), the ModelStates.IsValid still false. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550714/modelstate-isvalid-false-using-jquery-datepicker