# ModelState.IsValid = false using jquery datepicker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MovieMetadata))]
public partial class Movie
{

}

class MovieMetadata
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime releaseDate { get; set; }

    public string storyline { get; set; }

    public Binary poster { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime? duration { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Binary trailer { get; set; }
}
```

this is the controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "poster, trailer")]Movie movie, HttpPostedFileBase poster, HttpPostedFileBase trailer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //saving the movie
            OperationStatus opStatus = Repository.Save(movie);

            if (!opStatus.Status)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }

        return View(movie);
    }
```

This is the View:

```
@model MoviesModel.Movie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MoviesLayout.cshtml";
}

    @section createMovie{
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="gallMemberBox">

            <div class="leftFormContent">
                <a href="#">Movie Name</a>

                <div class="imgTmpl">
                    <!--solo hay que especificar el src de la imagen-->
                    <img src="../../Content/img/imgTest.jpg" alt="" />  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rightFormContent">

                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title)

                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)
                </div>

                <div>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.releaseDate)

                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.releaseDate)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.releaseDate)
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Create" />

            </div>

            <div class="clearBoth"></div>
        </div> 
    }
}
```

This is the template from Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js")

<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
</script>

@Html.TextBox("datepicker", null, new{id="datepicker"})
```

When I select a date and submit the form, the ModelState is false, and releaseDate comes with an error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the editor template, change it to something like this:

```
@model DateTime?

@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js")

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new{@class="datepicker"})

<script>
        $(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

Using the `TextBoxFor` will wire up the model binding correctly.

Also, I would recommend moving your `Styles.Render()` and `Scripts.Render()` to your `_Layout` if possible.  Since I changed the `datepicker()` to wire up a class, you could also move that if you wanted.

Comment: I tryied this and I got this exception when I was rendering my View The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'. The View has this line   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.releaseDate) and I put in my EditorTemplates folder the above code

Comment: Change the `@model DateTime` to `@model DateTime?`.  I'll update original answer also.

Comment: Can you explain me better why mvc needs to put null to the model item passed into the dictionary that it will render on the View?

Comment: Because the property (`releaseDate`) coming from your model is nullable and you can't directly assign a nullable `DateTime` to a not-nullable `DateTime`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with this line:

```
@Html.TextBox("datepicker", null, new{id="datepicker"})
```

Here, you are creating a textbox withe the name and id of "datepicker". So when you submit the form, MVC will try to find a property in Movie called "datepicker", which is why `releaseDate` is empty.

I don't think there is a need for the Editor Template, you can just use @krillgar's recommendation.

If you still want to use an Editor Template, you will need to get the field name using the following approach:

[How to get model's field name in custom editor template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615541/how-to-get-models-field-name-in-custom-editor-template)

Comment: I put this line and this does not work: @Html.TextBox("releaseDate", null, new{id="datepicker"})

Comment: Can you use the Developer Tools in your browser and go under Network so you can see what is being sent to the server when you submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a separate Textbox with an ID of datepicker, just use another EditorFor for the property, and add an HTML class to the object of datepicker, and use that instead.

**EDIT**

This would be the syntax to set it up. (In your "View" section of the code above)

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.releaseDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

Then your javascript would change to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To include this in your view instead, try something like the following:

```
    @Html.TextBox("releaseDate", Model.releaseDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new {id="datepicker" })
```

Remember to also include your JQuery refs later followed by the script block.